# ASP.NET MVC 4 HtmlHelper - mix decoded HTML with encoded HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, decode

I'm writing a helper method that will generate comment's HTML on a page and I want to be able to show a comment with "< script >alert("hello");< /script >" as it's content.

When using

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(comment.Content)
```

in a *.cshtml file, that script gets rendered as plain text.

But when using this HTML helper in a View:

```
@Html.PendingComment(comment)
```

the script gets rendered as HTML and gets executed:

```
public static IHtmlString PendingComment(this HtmlHelper helper, VoidCommentPending comment)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<p>" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(comment.Content) + "</p>");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Tried with "new HtmlString()", same result, and when I changed return result from IHtmlString to string, even paragraph tags got rendered as plain text.

Is it possible to mix encoding and decoding HTML strings in HtmlHelper or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so before storing comments into database, I use HttpUtility.Encode:

```
model.Content= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(model.Content);
```

Then I just removed decoding from my helper method

```
sb.Append("<p>" + comment.Content + "</p>");
```

and it shows "< script >alert("hello");< /script >" as plain text on my page.
Problem solved.

Esentially I was "double decoding". With HttpUtility.HtmlDecode this content:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;hello&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;
```

was getting decoded to "plain text" html, *which I wanted*, **but** then MvcHtmlString.Create was decoding it **again** and it got rendered as HTML.